# How to find hdfs-inputdir for ImportTsv

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hdfs, data-migration

From [this](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_importtsv), I was running following:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c <tablename> <hdfs-inputdir>
```

I am not able to figure out, what will be: `hdfs-inputdir`. I have created a directory in hdfs fs by : `hadoop fs -mkdir dataDir` and place my csv file in this folder using `copyFromLocal` option of `hadoop fs` command.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you didnt specify full path while doing copyFromLocal and mkdir. That directory will be created under `hdfs home` folder of user running mkdir and copyFromLocal command. Usually, all user folder are under `/user/${username}`

Comment: How this command should be ran:

I ran as `/usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,client_ref_id,created_at 'testtable' hadoop_data_folder/`,

but I get error:

 `java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumException: Checksum error: file:/home/saurabh/hadoop_data_folder/test_data.csv at 0 exp: 714250326 got: -129385732`